# Which port android app is using

Tags: android

My wifi works through proxy, so I am using rooted phone with asproxy to connect to the internet.

most of the apps use standard ports (that's my belief), but some uses special ports like play.google.com uses 5228 to connect.

is there a way to know which port my other apps are using (probably to listen) example mighty text so i can configure them in asproxy. I have tried logcat but i doesnot give much details.

logcat extract:

```
 W/com.Alsu.ASProxy(  757): Network connected, starting
> D/WifiWatchdogService(  251): (android.server.ServerThread) wi-fi
> (.f....) does not require the watchdog D/Tethering(  251):
> MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3 D/GTalkService( 2257): #####
> Network broadcast (connected=true) type=WIFI, state=CONNECTED
> I/MediaUploader( 6574): No need to wake up D/GTalkService( 2257):
> [GTalkConnection.1] ### networkStateChanged: active and curr network
> type/state are the same(1/CONNECTED), ignore D/CMStats ( 6594):
> CONNECTIVITY_ACTION: noConnectivity = false D/CMStats ( 6594):
> CONNECTIVITY_ACTION: starting service D/CMStats ( 6594): User has not
> opted in -- skipping reporting.
> **V/texty   ( 5190): Data connection is ON.** D/dalvikvm(  370): GC_CONCURRENT freed 390K, 45% free 3913K/7047K, external 133K/513K,
> paused 4ms+6ms W/KeyCharacterMap(  370): Can't open keycharmap file
> W/KeyCharacterMap(  370): Error loading keycharmap file
> '/system/usr/keychars/europa_keypad0.kcm.bin'.
> hw.keyboards.0.devname='europa_keypad0'
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/6642347/1321873